# What is the origin of "oh noodles!"

Tags: british-english, expressions, slang

Noodles are tasty. I like them, but why are they also used as an exclamation of dismay in the following?

> Oh Noodles!

Comment: Where do you hear this? It seems like a regional thing, in so far as I've not heard it.

Comment: Related later post: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37848

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has no real origin, just something one could say any other day. My friend says "Oh, fish!", and that doesn't have an etymology or an origin either, just an expression that someone might use idiosyncratically.

Comment: The first part of your answer doesn't gel with the second. *Noodles* seems more like a minced oath, as in your fish example.

Comment: Yes, that's a coherent answer :)

Comment: It's possibly a minced oath, but minced oaths usually resemble an actual rude word, like "darn" for "damn", "shoot" for "shit", etc. I'm not sure what "noodles" might be.

Answer (score 2):

In "[Two Towers](https://books.google.com/books?id=2jf8Tna_MxMC&pg=PA240&dq=%22Noodles!%20My%20beautiful%20rope!%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3l_W-gq75AhWAEFkFHVNOBnoQ6AF6BAgGEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Noodles!%20My%20beautiful%20rope!%22&f=false)" by J.R.R. Tolkien (1954), Sam Gamjee goes "Noodles!" as an exclamation. Based on the context, I'm guessing it's like "oh shit!"

> But Sam did not answer: he was staring back up the cliff. 'Ninnyhammers!' he said. 'Noodles! My beautiful rope! There it is tied to a stump, and we're at the bottom.'

Comment: No, this is not just an exclamation. Both _ninnyhammer_ and _noodle_ are epithets meaning "foolish". He is referring to themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that someone using such an expression indeed does NOT like noodles.  It's a euphemism.  Instead of saying some sort of expletive he's cleaned his diction up and used something he thinks that would be humorous.

I approve =)  I also LOVE noodles.

Comment: Since you love noodles so much, is it safe to assume that you also worship "_His Great Noodly Appendage_" and consider yourself a _Pastafarian_?  http://www.lumbercartel.ca/glossary/fsm.pl

Comment: HHAHAHAHA, oh that's definitely a first.  Unfortunately my favorite kind of noodle is the rice noodle.  In a traditional Pho its hard to beat.  Also enjoy egg noodles and hand made Korean noodles (actually...those suckers are the best).

But alas, I worship I AM, God of Abraham, Isaac and Jesus ;)  thanks for the link.  I got a good laugh =)

Comment: Excellent!  It's fun to make people laugh!

Comment: @Randolf. I have been touched by his noodly appendage.