# Use of "measles" as an interjection

Tags: interjections

I have a friend from Illinois USA who uses *measles* as an exclamation of frustration or disappointment. For example,

> Measles!  My flight was just canceled.

I find this odd. Is it commonly used this way?

Comment: See: [Origin of 'oh noodles!'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37315/what-is-the-origin-of-oh-noodles/37324#37324)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your question, I must say that I have never heard of "measles!" used as an interjection before, and that googling confirms its rarity (by not turning up any pertinent results).  So it's not common.  It may just be a quirk of your friend; I know of someone who says "sugar pie!" when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, anything can be used as interjection, as long as it is used to express strong emotions.

Comment: I don't think it has to be strong emotions.

Comment: Yeah I know. But... you know what I'n talking about.

Comment: My grandmother furthered this point in an attempt to reduce my bad language by her use of "windscreen wipers".