# What is a term describing offensive word replacement with made-up slang?

Tags: offensive-language

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What term describes a non-offensive substitute for a swear word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35156/what-term-describes-a-non-offensive-substitute-for-a-swear-word)

Is there a term for replacing one slang word with another made-up slang word?

For example `f*cking` => `fricking`, `fracking`, `smurfing`, `frelling`, or `freaking`

At what point do the made up words turn into recognized/official words? For example I'm pretty sure I can use most of the above replacements and people will know what I mean, `fricking` and `fracking` being most used.

Even if a replacement becomes commonly used, at what point would it end up in say the OED?