# Word for describing in a positive sense

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that means to say in a positive sense? For instance, when writers say that a person was *sexually assaulted* instead of saying *raped*.

Or people use *let go* instead of *fired*.

What is that called?

Comment: I don't think *sexually assaulted* is particularly positive.

Comment: Related: [What term describes a non-offensive substitute for a swear word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35156/what-term-describes-a-non-offensive-substitute-for-a-swear-word)

Comment: Also, 'sexually assaulted' covers more than just 'raped'.

Comment: I think these words/phrases _soften_ the thrust/intent of the original. As the others have mentioned, _sexual assault_ does not fall in this category. In any event, _assault_ is a pretty strong word; there's no _couching_ there.

Comment: @KitFox That depends who's doing it.

Comment: @KitFox: That's putting it mildly! I can't imagine how OP could think *sexually assaulted* was somehow a "euphemistic" version of *raped*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Such a usage is called a **Euphemism**.

> "A figure of rhetoric by which an unpleasant or offensive thing is described or referred to by a milder term" (Chambers)

Answer (score 3):

A euphemism.

(Note, though, that sexual assault is a crime distinct from rape.)

Comment: In most jurisdictions, "sexual assault" is the catch-all, ranging from a Roman Butt-Pinch to the most brutal instances of what we used to call "rape".  "Aggravated sexual assault" covers the more severe end of the spectrum.

Comment: Well, it irks me when the media uses this euphemism when writing about a rape. We as a cultured have become too sensitized. Also, this is the ugliest of acts, which people, if not careful, can confuse a situation as being, "not as bad" when they read about it through the use of euphemisms.

Comment: I Thank all of you for the reminder. I always forget that word. I agree with everything everyone has said.

Answer (score 1):

A slang term is **"sugar-coating the [bitter] pill."**