# Oh fudge knuckle!

Tags: expressions, minced-oaths, exclamations

What does this expression mean? I heard it in a video where the person said something like

> This sounds right, but in fact, son of a gun, or as my younger son
>   would say, fudge knuckle, it goes wrong in the end.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/35156/8019

Comment: or to save clicking effort, it's a 'minced oath' for the f-word.

Comment: There is actually a grocery store (chain?) in St. Louis called Fudpuckers.  Just thought I'd throw this bit of trivia out there for fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never heard that expression before but it sounds like one of those nonsense expressions that are often used as a general exclamation. I would guess, too, that *fudge* is meant to be a euphemism for *fuck*, as such euphemisms are common in these nonsense phrases.

Comment: Agreed, and I will point out that it starts with the same "fuh" sound, and the "uck" in the second word is stressed.  So you really are saying the f-word, just slightly broken up.

Comment: Like in *fire truck*.

Comment: @Hellion: A very good point, thanks for making the clarification!