# Term for a more polite word used in place of a vulgar word

Tags: single-word-requests, literary-device

What is the term for a polite word or phrase that is used in place of a vulgar word or phrase?

> "Prostitute" is a _____ for "hooker"

Comment: In this particular case, I don't think either is particularly vulgar or polite. "Hooker" is an *informal* synonym for a prostitute, so the latter is the formal term.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [Non-offensive substitute for a swear word](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/35156/) ?

Comment: another one you may be thinking of: double entendre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Euphemism.

Dictionary definition is: a mild or indirect word or expression substituted for one considered to be too harsh or blunt when referring to something unpleasant or embarrassing.

Comment: Yes! I can't believe I couldn't think of that... still, I'll wait a bit to see if there are any other terms I can't remember at the moment. I mean, to be fair, prostitute isn't a "euphemism" for hooker the way "chasing the dragon" is a euphemism for getting high. It's explicit; I tend to think of euphemisms as being implicit.

Answer (score 0):

Amiable or affable;

> "Prostitute" is an amiable term for "hooker".

or

> "Prostitute" is an affable term for "hooker".

---

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/amiable?s=t) defines *amiable* as:

> having or showing pleasant, good-natured personal qualities; affable:

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/affable?s=t) defines *affable* as

> pleasantly easy to approach and to talk to; friendly; cordial; warmly polite:

Comment: Amiable and affable are used to describe people, not terms.  The prostitute, or hooker, might have been amiable or affable (so as to be hired for services), but not the words themselves.