# Origin of “Fish” as an exclamation or mild oath

Tags: etymology

One of the characters in *Bojack Horseman* would often say “fish” as an exclamation or mild oath (mary, mr. Shakespeare).  I just thought this was a peculiarity of the show, but I heard another usage today in *King of the Hill* in the same exact manner.

Perhaps the two shows are linked, but I suspect this is not the case.  Does anyone know if “fish” has been used in such a manner?

Comment: They are avoiding cursing, uttering an expletive.  In general, you  will often hear this in the form of oh sugar, of fudge, etc.

Comment: I saw a Tourette's sufferer on TV who had taught herself to explete ***biscuit*** so as not to cause offence.

Comment: Related: [Non-offensive substitute for a swear word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35156/non-offensive-substitute-for-a-swear-word).

Comment: ... but I am not convinced that [**euphemism** NOUN](https://www.lexico.com/definition/euphemism) *is* a synonym for an **expletive**. Its meaning is more like the US use of 'bathroom' for 'toilet', or 'in the family way' to mean 'pregnant'.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think Bruce meant _uttering an expletive_ as a synonym for cursing!

Answer (score 3):

It is a shortened form of a minced oath:

From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/edible-interjections/cheerio):

> Odsfish! Definition: a mild oath

> There have been a great number of ways that the English speaking people have used od as a stand-in for God (or, as the Oxford English Dictionary memorably puts it, as a “euphemistic substitute for God in asseverative or exclamatory formulae”). Odsfish, which is the less-common variant of odds fish, is thought to be a euphemistic way of saying "God's fish."

> *Ay, ay, trust to that, and hang me, quoth Panurge, yours is a very pretty Fancy; Od's Fish, did I not give you a sufficient account of the Elements Transmutation, and the Blunders that are made of Roast for Boyld, and Boyld for Roast?*- François Rabelais, Pantagruel’s Voyage to the Oracle of the Bottle (trans. by P. A. Motteux), 1694

OED, which I trust more, adds

> **od's fish int.**  [perhaps alteration of **God's flesh**]

> 1634   T. Heywood & R. Brome Late Lancashire Witches v. sig. L2v   *O here comes more o' your Naunts, Naunt Dickenson & Naunt Hargrave, ods fish and your Granny Johnson too.*

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the comment by @Bruce Murray.

The technical term for this is *euphemism*. Specifically this is a case of *phonetic modification*. Something that is said that, on the surface, sounds innocent but which is similar to a word that would be unacceptable in polite company. See below for further explanation.

> Types of Euphemisms Within the definition of euphemism, there are many
> different sub-categories. Here are some of the different types of
> euphemisms:
>
> ...
>
> Phonetic modification: We modify strong swear words or words that are
> not meant to be spoken lightly (i.e., God or Jesus) so that the new
> phonetic euphemism sounds very similar to the original, but just
> different enough so that it’s inoffensive. Modifications may take the
> case of shortening the word or expression (Jeez, What the);
> intentional mispronunciations (shoot, shut the front door, dang,
> fudge); or using an acronym or one letter to represent the curse word
> (WTF, B-word, A-hole).
>
> http://www.literarydevices.com/euphemism/

---

**Note**

For those not familiar with English, I'll explain some of the above.

shoot ---> shit

dang ---> damn

fudge ---> f*ck

The point is that the listener is fooled into thinking the actual word is coming but then a slightly different word is actually spoken.

Comment: I would characterize these more specifically as [minced oaths](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/minced-oath.html).

Comment: @choster - I'm not sure that you are being *more* specific. I believe that minced oaths are the same as Phonetic-modification euphemisms. Certainly your phrase is more euphonious. However if you can say how the two concepts are different I'm happy to learn.

Comment: A minced oath is a euphemism, but not every euphemism is a minced oath.

Comment: @Weather Vane - Where did I say that it was?

Comment: I was remarking how they are different, from the comment above which was actually addressd to choster, sorry. But come to think of it I don't think that a minced oath even *is* a euphemism, which is a polite *term* for something.

Comment: How do you distinguish "term" from a word or a phrase?  I think we must be talking at cross-purposes.

Comment: I am not attempting to distinguish, but you may try.

Comment: Ah! It makes more sense that you were replying to choster!  Anyway I'm happy with my original answer so I'll stick with it.